# How to strip trailing zeros in PHP

Tags: php, string

Could anyone give me an explanation (and maybe an example) on how to strip the trailing zeros from a number using PHP.

For example:

```
"Lat":"37.422005000000000000000000000000","Lon":"-122.84095000000000000000000000000"
```

Would be turned in to:

```
"Lat":"37.422005","Lon":"-122.84095"
```

I am trying to strip the zeros to make it more readable. I tried using `str_replace()` but this replaced the zeros inside the number too.

Comment: dude, add it to 0, 

$a += 0; check detail here: https://nabtron.com/kiss-code/

Comment: @NabeelKhan I would recommend assigning `$a + 0` to a new variable instead of using `+=` which will change the type of `$a`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Forget all the rtrims, and regular expressions, coordinates are floats and should be treated as floats, just prepend the variable with `(float)` to cast it from a string to a float:

```
$string = "37.422005000000000000000000000000";
echo (float)$string;
```

output:

```
37.422005
```

The actual result you have are floats but passed to you as strings due to the HTTP Protocol, it's good to turn them back into thier natural form to do calculations etc on.

Test case: http://codepad.org/TVb2Xyy3

**Note**: Regarding the comment about floating point precision in PHP, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3726761/353790

Comment: a good point, would make it easier when using the data on the phone for plotting points.

Comment: Bad solution. Floats have finite precision; this can truncate significant digits.

Comment: I don't think this was a bad solution, I think it's one of the better solutions for this language, if the OP requires precision, then the OP should look at using C, C#, Python etc that do support finite precision.

Comment: i guess those wont be useful if the number is "0.0000085" for example, result will be something like "8.5E-5"

Comment: lol, dude, simply add the string to 0 ($a += 0;) ... the way your answer started started I thought you were better than the rest here

Comment: @NabeelKhan I know, right? Somebody did post exactly that solution but it's just not getting the love that this answer is getting for some reason.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 but we know at least :)

Comment: your solution only works if no special locale is set. For instance, a German String would be `$s = "37,45340000000000"`, and then your cast to float will fail.

Comment: Bad answer.. it fails if the number has thousand separators

Answer (score 54):

Try with [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$number = rtrim($number, "0");
```

If you have a decimal number terminating in 0's (e.g. 123.000), you *may* also want to remove the **decimal separator**, which may be **different depending on the used locale**. To remove it reliably, you may do the following:

```
$number = rtrim($number, "0");
$locale_info = localeconv();
$number = rtrim($number, $locale_info['decimal_point']);
```

This of course is not a bullet-proof solution, and may not be the best one. If you have a number like 12300.00, it won't remove the trailing 0's from the integer part, but you can adapt it to your specific need.

Comment: In my case, I did the following:
    rtrim(rtrim($number, "0"),".")
Because I also had to remove the decimal if a whole number was being shown (for example, this will show numbers 2.00, 1.00, 28.50, 16.25 I wanted to show as 2, 1, 28.5, 16.25, rather than 2., 1., 28.5, 16.25)

Comment: I like this solution because you can preserve commas inserted with number_format: rtrim(rtrim(number_format($number, 2), '0'), '.') In my case, I don't need to worry about whole numbers like 100, because I'm pulling a decimal value from the database.

Comment: @Staysee isn't it possible that you pull a decimal value from the database that looks like: `"123.0000000"`? Now what do you have?

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to also remove the decimal separator according to the current locale.

Comment: Suppose you got a string like `".000"`. I suppose you'd want your function to return `"0"` instead of `""`.

Comment: rtrim(rtrim($num, '0'), '.'); work fine for me.

Answer (score 41):

You'll run into a lot of trouble if you try trimming or other string manipulations. Try this way.

```
$string = "37.422005000000000000000000000000";

echo $string + 0;
```

Outputs:

```
37.422005
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Any idea how this works? Coz it does work

Comment: It's very simple. You start out with a string that has a lot of trailing zeros. PHP cannot add the integer `0` to a string so it first converts the string to a numeric type then adds `0` to it. You end up with a number, not a string. Numeric types have no use for trailing zeroes. You should be careful about automatic type conversion but in a case like this, it's entirely predictable and safe.

Comment: Wow! I think this is the definition of "too good to be true"! Like someone already observed, this could do with a little explanation.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo Thanks. I already posted an explanation in the comments.

Comment: +1 from me. This is better solution than ```rtrim```. If the number has no any other number behind decimal (ex : **8.00000000**), ```rtrim``` will strangely get result **8.** when printed as String, it has annoying unnecessary dot of course, while this solution gives solid result **8** which is desired by everyone. Seriously, PHP always do something that is Mathematically illegal move.

Comment: @poring91 you can't call the behavior of `rtrim` 'mathematically illegal`. It is not math function and it's not operating on a number. It's a string function operating on a string and it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. It's just not the appropriate function for this case.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 I understand about that. For clarification, the thing I said about "Mathematically illegal move" is when calculate string data with number data like this solution. The operation PHP do is... convert string that is shaped like number to appropriate number and calculate it in mathematically way. We all know that String is array, and calculate a group of data with single of data because the array is shaped like number is illegal move, by doing so feels like PHP is cheating the logic. Yes, it gives programmer easy access and it helps me.

Comment: other language might doing different behavior such as appending string like BASIC or reject it because the operator cannot process array and primitive data (I forget which language it was)

Comment: Whilst this works for the OPs question, this solution will error if the number being trimmed is in thousands and uses comma separators.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I did the following, extending other answers here:

```
rtrim((strpos($number,".") !== false ? rtrim($number, "0") : $number),".");
```

Because I also had to remove the decimal if a whole number was being shown

As an example, this will show the following numbers

```
2.00, 1.00, 28.50, 16.25
```

As

```
2, 1, 28.5, 16.25
```

Rather than

```
2., 1., 28.5, 16.25
```

Which, to me, is not showing them correctly.

Latest edit also stops numbers such as "100" from being rtrim'ed to 1, by only trimming the rightmost 0's if a decimal is encountered.

Comment: Will fail on numbers such as "100" (strips significant 0s).

Comment: Thanks Mark, solution has been updated (albeit 18 months after your comment!)

Comment: Redacted my downvote. Looks a lot like [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19777740/65387) now.

Comment: What will happen if you start with `".000"`?

Comment: Exactly what you would expect to happen. It would return an empty string - because you've stripped out the zeroes AND the decimal place... the issue here is that the original request was asking about STRING manipulation, and not working with actual numbers. IF you needed it to return a numeric value, you could `(float)rtrim((strpos($number,".") !== false ? rtrim($number, "0") : $number),".");` or simply `+0` to the original string.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `floatval(val);`.

```
 <?php
 echo floatval( "37.422005000000000000000000000000" );
 ?>
```

results in

> 37.422005

Comment: I don't think it's the best choice in the first place but, if you're going to convert to a float, don't use `floatval()`. Just cast it as a float with `(float)`. Always avoid calling extra functions if possible. The use case for `floatval()` is when you want to convert a whole array of values to float, then you can call `array_map('floatval', $someArray);`

Comment: Both `floatval` and `(float)` turn my number into scientific notation `.0E-7`

Answer (score 7):

Most of these solutions will trim significant digits in numbers such as "100" (no trailing decimal). Here's a simple solution that doesn't have this problem:

```
function TrimTrailingZeroes($nbr) {
    if(strpos($nbr,'.')!==false) $nbr = rtrim($nbr,'0');
    return rtrim($nbr,'.') ?: '0';
}
```

I think that covers all the different scenarios.

```
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('0')
=> "0"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('01')
=> "01"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('01.0')
=> "01"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('01.01')
=> "01.01"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('01.010')
=> "01.01"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('.0')
=> "0"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('.1')
=> ".1"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('.10')
=> ".1"
>>> TrimTrailingZeroes('3141592653589793.238462643383279502880000000000000000000000000000')
=> "3141592653589793.23846264338327950288"
```

Comment: The string `'.0000'` yields empty string. I believe you would want `'0'`.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 Fair enough. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to strip the excess zeros away from the end but only to a certain decimal place, this is a useful expression to do just that (for example 0.30000 will show 0.30 and 0.0003000 will show 0.0003).

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\\.[0-9]{2})[0]+\$/","",$number);
```

Of course the {2} controls the decimal place limit.

Comment: +1 for using the most complex way to solve a simple problem :-)

Comment: `"0.0003000"` will **not** convert to `"0.0003"`. You've only allowed for up to 2 non-zero digits after the decimal. This regex won't even match. You're better off using `number_format($x,2,'.','')` if this is the result you want.

Comment: Do not use regular expressions for something like this. Especially don't use such a overly complex regular expression.

Comment: simple yet beautiful solution!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [round function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) which is more able to manipulate numbers than a `replace`.

```php
round('37.422005000000000000000000000000', 32); 
//float(37.422005)

round('-122.84095000000000000000000000000', 32); 
//float(-122.84095)
```

The resulting rounded number will be based upon your [`precision`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) *(default 14)* setting.

Comment: Oddly this is actually a [viable solution](https://3v4l.org/R3CN9), by specifying a high precision like `32`, it prevents the supplied number from being rounded. `round('-122.84095000000000000000000000000', 32) = -122.84095` However since it converts the value to a real number, it still suffers from the floating point issue that casting the string value does when working with high `ini_set('precision', 32)`.

Comment: Good solution, but it works just for 4 decimal places in my case. for 5, ... it shows `e`

Answer (score 3):

Trims trailing zeroes, but only after the decimal place -- we wouldn't want to convert 100 -> 1, for example. It will also strip the period if only zeros follow it.

```
function trim_zeros($str) {
    if(!is_string($str)) return $str;
    return preg_replace(array('`\.0+$`','`(\.\d+?)0+$`'),array('','$1'),$str);
}
```

Comment: At least you've considered a case that almost everyone else has ignored. Still, no.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 What's your beef with this solution? Yours doesn't allow arbitrarily large numbers/high precision.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I try to avoid preg functions unless they're absolutely necessary. Still, if you need precision of over 14 decimal places or so, this might be the best solution.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 Regexes aren't really slow unless you're running thousands of them. Still, I did come up with another solution that doesn't require them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19777740/65387

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solution that accepts a minimum and maximum amount of decimal places, this should work:

```
/**
 * Displays up to 4 decimal places, with a minimum of 2 decimal places, trimming unnecessary zeroes
 *
 * @param mixed $number
 * @param int $minimumDecimals
 * @param int $maximumDecimals
 * @return string
 */
function rate_format($number, int $minimumDecimals = 2, int $maximumDecimals = 4): string
{
    $formatted = number_format($number, $maximumDecimals, '.', ',');
    $minimumLength = strpos($formatted, '.') + $minimumDecimals + 1;
    $extra = rtrim(substr($formatted, $minimumLength), "0");
    return substr($formatted, 0, $minimumLength) . $extra;
}


// rate_format("1.2500") returns "1.25"
// rate_format("1.2525") returns "1.2525"
// rate_format("1.25256") returns "1.2526"
// rate_format("1") returns "1.00"
```

This is hard coded to use the US locale, but should be easily adjusted for other locales.

Answer (score 3):

**Remove Trailing zeros + Thousand Separator**

```
function specialFormat($number,  $decimals = 8)
{
    return rtrim(rtrim(number_format($number, $decimals), '0'), '.');
}
```

---

```
input: 0.00000008 => output: 0.00000008
input: 1560.1854500 => output: 1,560.18545
input: 1560.00 => output: 1,560
```

Comment: A simple solution that accounts for comma separation which many of the other answers do not.

Comment: Why would a latitude/longitude question ever need to bother with thousands place separators???

Answer (score 1):

For me, I need a further solution to convert exponential values and simple numbers like 10000 to the last non-zero significant digit

```
/* Convert any value to the least significant value */
function toDecimal($val) {

  // Convert any exponential sign to proper decimals
  $val = sprintf("%lf", $val);

  if (strpos($val, '.') !== false) {
      $val = rtrim(rtrim($val, '0'), '.');
  }

  return $val;
}

// Test cases
echo toDecimal(1000.000) . "\n";
echo toDecimal(1E-5) . "\n";
echo toDecimal(1E+5) . "\n";
echo toDecimal(1234.56) . "\n";
echo toDecimal(1234.5700) . "\n";
echo toDecimal(1234000) . "\n";
echo toDecimal(-1e10) . "\n";

// Results
1000
0.00001
100000
1234.56
1234.57
1234000
-10000000000
```

Comment: No. With the exception of `1E-5` (which has nothing to do with this question), all of these 'tests' would turn out exactly the same without running them through your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rtrim() ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php ):

```
rtrim( "37.422005000000000000000000000000" , "0" )
```

Just make sure that there will be a decimal point.

Comment: IMO, rtrim() is a better choice than preg_replace()

Comment: @BobbyJack but just barely.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, interesting.  I have used this:

```
// remove leading zeros
$output = ltrim ($output, "0");

// remove trailing 0s.
$temp=explode(".",$output);
$temp[1]=rtrim($temp[1],"0");
$output = $temp[0];
if (!empty($temp[1])) $output.='.'.$temp[1];

return $output;
```

This removes trailing 0s from the number AFTER the first decimal point.  Otherwise a number like 100 becomes 1.

Since I was doing a comparison, using the float technique caused problems.  Hope this helps?

Answer (score -1):

```
function trimTrailingZeros($number, $decimal_separator){
    //Split the number by the decimal separator
    $array = explode($decimal_separator, $number);
    //the first item in the array is the whole number
    $whole_number = $array[0];
    //the second item in the array are the decimal values
    $decimal_values= $array[1];
    //remove trailing zeros from the decimal values using rtrim()
    $decimal_values = rtrim($decimal_values,'0');
    //if decimal values is not empty string, add the decimal separator;
    $point=$decimal_values?$decimal_separator:'';
    //return the adjusted number;
    return $whole_number.$point.$decimal_values;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

`preg_replace` will do the trick:

```
$lat=preg_replace('/0+$/','',$lat);
```

Comment: -1 because although this works, this is not a good use-case for regex.

Comment: @Unkwntech too processor intensive for the simplicity of the task?

Comment: @Shad, just overkill.  Regular Expressions are usually not the answer, if one can use type (string/int/float) manipulations it is likely to be faster, and less prone to problems in the future.  For example compare your solution to RobertPitt's solution, in yours what happens if $lat is `10`, and what happens in RobertPitt's?  Those reasons aside, also consider what happens when a developer who doesn't know regular expressions comes across your solution while trying to fix a bug.

Comment: One more reason not to do this, consider the string: `"123.0000000"`