# Trim zeros to the right of a decimal place and decimal point often

Tags: php, regex

I have been handling long numbers in PHP. Like the following examples.

```
12.020000
12.000000
```

To get rid of trailing zeros and the decimal point I have been using the following inside a function.

```
return rtrim(rtrim($str, "0"),".");
```

So the above turns out like.

```
12.02
12
```

It was a bit short sighted as when `1000` gets entered it gets turned into `1`.

Can someone please help me with the code to remove trailing zeros after the decimal point only?

Bonus points if the code removes the decimal place but I can always feed it into `rtim($str,".")`.

EDIT: To be clear, I am stripping the decimal place and zeros only when displaying to the screen. Also casting to float is not an option as I also handle numbers like 0.00000001 which come out like 1.0e-9 sort of thing.

Comment: Why not use number_format() or sprintf(), rather than messing about with rtrim()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip trailing zeros in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149129/how-to-strip-trailing-zeros-in-php)

Comment: "If string does not contain `.` add it at end before feeding into your expression" - so `1000` becomes `1000.` and the dot "protects" the zeros.

Comment: `(float) $str` and that's all

Comment: Casting to floats does not look good with numbers like 0.00000001 which I am handling. It makes then unreadable to general users.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using string to hold numbers? Cast it to float and it'll solve your problem.

```
$string = '12.020000';
$number = (float) $string; // will be 12.02
```

Then, if you want to use it as string (but why?)

```
$string = (string) $number;
```

Comment: We posted at the same time, and  your answer is better.

Comment: @JasonSilver My answer was `answered 7 mins ago` and your `answered 2 mins ago` ;)

Comment: Sorry, when I clicked the question, there was no other answer @ElonThan

Comment: That's terrible when the number is 0.000001 as it comes out as 1-E5 or there abouts.

Answer (score 3):

The thing that perplexes me about your question is that extra zeros won't be included in a number variable without intentionally adding them with number_format. (This may be why someone down-voted it).

Normally you don't want to use string functions (meant for text) on variables that hold numbers. If you want to round off a number, use a function like round.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

There's also number_format, which can format numbers by adding zero padding: (it doesn't actuall round, just trims off excess numbers).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Since your zeros are appearing, it's likely that you simply need to multiple the variable by 1, which will essentially convert a string to a number.

Good luck!

Comment: You should use `(float)` or `floatval()` to cast to float, don't use other workarounds.

Comment: Internally the system uses the full numbers. I am only trimming numbers when displaying to the screen. Casting to float is no good as I need to also display number like 0.00000001 which come out in an unfriendly way to users with float.