# Storing decimal value as it is in decimal field in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in MySql `Decimal(10,2)` and I am trying to insert a float value like `1.1` in it. Unfortunately it is storing that value as 1.10. How can I store that value as it is, because the system will not be able to distinguish between 1.1 and 1.10.

Due to some reason I cannot change the Data Type to VARCHAR OR STRING. On the server side I am using php.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems a presentation tier concern - why not leave the value in the database as a Decimal, but then when presenting the data to the user, cast it to [float or rtrim it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5149186/314291) in php?.

Comment: If i use float or rtrim function it will discard 0 from both 1.1 and 1.10 Leaving 1.1 for both entries

Comment: It seems you are trying to audit what the user typed in (? e.g. certainty of precision). I would then add an additional `varchar` column to store this, although for all numeric purposes, I would also keep the Decimal column.

Comment: Yes I am trying to store what ever user enters, The user can enter 1 or 1.1 or 1.10, But we do not have any other data type to deal such issues in MySql?

Answer (score 0):

Your specification `Decimal(10,2)` is forcing it to save as a 2 place decimal. You can either use another data type like float OR you can trim it in your code using [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
rtrim($value, 0);
```

Comment: If i use float dataType, I think it will not work because it will store 1.1 as 1.1, And 1.10 as 1.1, And on the other hand if i use rtrim function it will discard 0 from 1.1 and 1.10 Leaving 1.1 for both entries

Answer (score 0):

1.1 and 1.10 are both the same or do you have any other specification

Comment: Definitely different, For Example Exercise no, 1.1 and 1.10 are different.