# how to get exactly 2 digits after decimal point

Tags: php

Can any one help this please

1. 11.1 -> 11.10
2. 11.11 -> 11.11

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) function, like so:

```
$number = number_format(1.1, 2);
```

This will return `1.10`.

Comment: Your answer is good. But i want (1 -> 11.1 to 11.10), (11.11 to 11.11)

Comment: Yes, that's what it is. The first parameter of number_format() is your input. So you can put 11.1 instead of 1.1 and check the output.

Answer (score 1):

i think it may help you

```
<?php
 echo preg_match('/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/',23.22); //ouput 1
 echo preg_match('/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/',23.222); //ouput 0
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = "11.11";

echo (float)$string;

?>
```

This could do the trick.

You may go through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149129/how-to-strip-trailing-zeros-in-php) for further information.