# How to remove 0(zero number) from php variable?

Tags: php

I try to remove zero number from php variable using php function, but not work.

I try to use `round` or `floor` or `ceil` but not work.

How can I do that?

```
2.00 ===> 2
2.05 ===> 2.05 (not remove zero)
2.50 ===> 2.5
2.55 ===> 2.55 (not remove zero)
```

Comment: floor/ceil will not work on 2.50 because that is not mathematically correct (will give you 2 or 3).

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code and your attempts

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149129/how-to-strip-trailing-zeros-in-php

Comment: `$value = rtrim($value, '.0');` would be one way, but not so good if your number is `200`

Comment: You're confusing _numbers_ for _string representation of numbers_. No idea why you think mathematical functions like `round` or `floor` would achieve this formatting.

Comment: @MarkBaker - `$value = rtrim($value, '.0');` will trim all trailing zeros: http://ideone.com/a4lSIL

Comment: @Mike - I know it will, I said that an hour ago

Comment: Need the PHP source code of your attempts. Otherwise typecasting to float or double as @Mike explained should work. http://ideone.com/8hyIFy

Answer (score 0):

You must be having string variable. Please convert it to float as (float)$var and you will lose these zeros if you print the result out.

Other option is to use rtrim on string to remove the 0 and . from the end. see examples here http://php.net/rtrim

Comment: Trim will remove all leading zeros: `2 === trim(200,'0');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$list = array("2.00", "2.05", "2.50", "2.55");
foreach($list as $val)
   echo (double) $val . "</br>";
```

Output:

```
2
2.05
2.5
2.55
```

Comment: @robertdewere - See my answer below for a more in-depth explanation and links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
number_format((float)$your_number, 2, '.', '');
```

I had the same problem. Function *number_format()* returns number as string so it will not remove zeros at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the value to a [Float Type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) (double, float, real), which will drop all leading or trailing zeros (after the decimal).

```
2.5 === (double) "2.50"
```

Be aware, however, that this does not format your number other than removing the 0's (this does not ensure a money format). For formatting, see [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
2.5 === (double) number_format('2.501', 2, '.', '');
```

Example:

```
(float) 2.00 === 2
(float) 2.05 === 2.05 // (not remove zero)
(float) 2.50 === 2.5
(float) 2.55 === 2.55 // (not remove zero)
```

And a proof: http://ideone.com/wimBHm

An interesting thing to note is that the test `(float) 2.00 === 2` actually does not pass, this is because `2` is actually of type `(int)`, and therefore fails the `===` test, however, as you can see, the output is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
$price = '2.00';
$price2 = '2.50';
$price3 = '2.05';

function formatPrice($price)
{
   /* Format number with 2 decimal places, then remove .00, then right trim any 0 */
   return rtrim(str_replace('.00', '', number_format($price, 2)), '0');
}

echo formatPrice($price); //2
echo formatPrice($price2); //2.5
echo formatPrice($price3); //2.05
```

Comment: They want to remove the last `0` in `2.50`

Comment: Updated. I didn't catch that.

Comment: The example outputs provided do not match the actual outputs (http://ideone.com/4MnQIe), and the solution requires the use of 3 functions, 2 of which are effectively redundant (trimming 0's).  It is not concise, performant or easy to understand.