# Print value without trailing zeros in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to print a value here, I am getting a value with four zeros .0000
125.000, I want to remove it and display just 125

```
@if(empty($product->qty_available))
    Availble Qty (Null)
@else
    Availble Qty ({{$product->qty_available}})
@endif
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149129/how-to-strip-trailing-zeros-in-php

Comment: Hi, it's printing the exact text (float)123.0000

Comment: Is it a float type/column? Do you cast it to float? Does it have to be float? Why not use int for quantity?

Comment: is (float) inside the double square brackets?

Comment: Also yeah @brombeer's solution is the better solution

Comment: Dude, you did not give any update?

Comment: @nice_dev your solution worked for me, i am new here i am currently at 10 points i can't up vote unless you give up vote to my question

Comment: @JustNaffys That's fine. I just want you to tick mark the answer that is most apt to your question, so that future researchers know there is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a [`ceil`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) value of the float. If it equals the integer part of the float before the decimal, we print the integer form of it, else go for the float as is.

```
@if(empty($product->qty_available))
    Availble Qty (Null)
@else
    Availble Qty ({{ ceil($product->qty_available) == (int)$product->qty_available ? (int)$product->qty_available : $product->qty_available}})
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with quantity there is no reason to use float, you should use int instead. But if you have to and you want no decimals you should try this:

```
@if(empty($product->qty_available))
    Availble Qty: (Null)
@else
    $product->qty_available = rtrim(rtrim($product->qty_available, "0"),".")
    Availble Qty: ({{$product->qty_available}})
@endif
```

This solution will remove both the (.) and the sequence of zeros of your string

Comment: Or you could simply do `(int)$product->qty_available` to cast the `float` to an `int`.