# Rounded decimal in edit form Symfony2 + Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, decimal

How do I set the decimal precision and scale within the symfony2 entity?  I've defined latitude in longitude fields using decimal data type in my entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision="10", scale="6", nullable=true)
 */
protected $latitude;
```

When persisting new object it saves decimal correctly (I can see 52.406374 in phpMyAdmin). However when displaying edit form the number is rounded to **52,406** and after updating it is stored in mysql as 52.406000. Probably something is wrong with my Doctrine configuration, but I don't know what.

Why is the latitude and longitude getting rounded?

**Found a solution:**

Symfony's Form component renders decimal form field as type="text".  When using:

```
->add('latitude', 'number', array(
    'precision' => 6,
))
```

It is rendered properly. The thread from comment doesn't describe my problem.
I guess they have already fixed bug with 'convert to float' precision.
When I was displaying latitude in twig template it was showing proper (not rounded) value.

Comment: Isn't it caused by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635500/doctrine-2-decimal-can-only-contain-14-digits)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the problem is not due to your doctrine mapping.
Look at this reference documentation for [NumberType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html).

It is what you use? You probably have to change the precision.

Answer (score 4):

**How to set the symfony decimal type precision and scale:**

Set it in your entity, like this:

```
protected $mycolumn;
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=14, scale=8, nullable=true)
*/
```

This sets the datatype in the MySQL database:

```
mycolumn decimal(14,8)
```

[What do scale and precision mean when specifying a decimal field type in Doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940574/what-do-scale-and-precision-mean-when-specifying-a-decimal-field-type-in-doctrin)

Answer (score 3):

In Symfony3.2 you should use scale:

```
$builder->add('lat', NumberType::class, array('scale' => 8));
```

> This specifies how many decimals will be allowed until the field
>   rounds the submitted value (via rounding_mode). For example, if scale
>   is set to 2, a submitted value of 20.123 will be rounded to, for
>   example, 20.12 (depending on your rounding_mode).