# A simple Java code that returns unexpectedly false while it is intened to return true

Tags: java

The following simple code in Java contains hardly 3 statements that returns unexpectedly **false** though it looks like that it should return **true**.

```
package temp;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        

        long temp = 2000000000;
        float f=temp;

        System.out.println(f<temp+50);
    }
}
```

---

The above code should obviously display **true** on the console but it doesn't. It displays **false** instead. Why?

Comment: Why are you converting it to a `float` in the first place?

Comment: Actually this code has no significance of its own. I just wanted to check why was this condition evaluated to false and it somewhat took me by surprise and I just decided to ask here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because [floating point arithmetic != real number arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision/3726761#3726761).

When `f` is assigned `2000000000`, it gets converted to `2.0E9`. Then when you add 50 to `2.0E9`, its value doesn't change. So actually, `(f == temp + 50)` is `true`.

If you need to work with large numbers but require precision, you'll have to use something like [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
long temp = 2000000000;
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(temp);

System.out.println(d.compareTo(new BigDecimal(temp+50)) < 0);
```

Will print `true` as one would expected.

(although in your case I don't know why you'd need to use a datatype other than `long`).