# Strange behavior in simple arithmetic

Tags: php, math, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange addition of numeric strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423270/strange-addition-of-numeric-strings-in-php)

```
$r = 1.0 - 0.8 - 0.2;
var_dump($r);
```

I get float -5.5511151231258E-17.
The same result i get in C++ and C#.

MySQL i get result 0.0 via query:

```
SELECT 1.0 - 0.8 - 0.2
```

Comment: *General reference question* http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let it be clear: `0.8` has finite representation in decimal because it has value `8/10¹`.

But in base 2, it has value: 1/2 + 1/4 + 0/8 + 0/16 + 1/32 + 1/64 + 0/128 + ... and it has no end, like one third has no end in decimal representation (`0.333…`) but would be `0.1` in base 3.

```
0.8 = 0.110011001100110011001100... in binary
0.2 = 0.001100110011001100110011... in binary
```

Your computer stores floating point values in binary representation. So, there is a loss of precision when you add, subtract, multiply, etc. numbers.

C++, C and C# are compiled languages, and floats are stored on typically 4 or 8 bytes. You cannot store 0.8 in a float.

MySQL might tell you 0 because it truncates the results of the calculation.

If you want a library that performs calculations without losses of precision in any base, look up GMPlib.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid it by using [BCMath](http://br.php.net/bc) ([bcsub()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.bcsub.php) for this case). Or you can simply [round()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) (note that you can set the precision on 2nd argument). For all cases you will receive `-0`, if you need positive `0` just use [abs()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php).

See what I talk about [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dKHH6S).

**Code example**:

```
<?php

    echo 'Direct: ' . ( 1.0 - 0.8 - 0.2 ) . '<br/>';

    echo 'BC Math: ' . bcsub( bcsub('1.0', '0.8'), '0.2' ) . '<br/>';
    echo 'Round: ' . round( 1.0 - 0.8 - 0.2 ) . '<br/>';
    echo 'Absolute: ' . abs( round( 1.0 - 0.8 - 0.2 ) ) . '<br/>';

?>
```