# Do not understand how this simple php code works

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Math Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision)

The following php code outputs 7 but I expect 8. Why the difference?

```
<?php echo (int)((0.1+0.7)*10); ?>
```

Comment: In floating point arithmetic 0.1 + 0.7 can equal 0.79999999999999999997 which casts to 7..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because due to inaccurate floating point representations, 0.1+0.7 is not **exactly** equal to 0.8. It might be some very tiny bit less than that. And when you use `int(..)`, it truncates it to 7.

Comment: Any idea how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: to circumvent it, use bcmath - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php - gmp - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php - or similar, or use the appropriate rounding rather than simply casting to int

Comment: Looks like this works: `(int)(string)((0.1+0.7)*10);` But it's not an universal solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also thought about multiplying with 10, rounding, dividing by ten, and then proceeding to do whatever it was, but the error might persist regardlessly.

Comment: @MartinsBriedis: Try doing the same thing with `printf(..)` with a higher decimal precision. Arik-so: The answer is there is always a better way of doing it depending on what you want to do.

Comment: In *this particular case*, `round((0.1+0.7)*10);`

Answer (score 1):

Others already pointed out the problem. If you're working with a fixed number of decimal places (for example, when working with money), you're better off calculating and storing cents and convertig them back to Dollars/Euros/Whatever when showing the values to the user.