# How to convert Meters to Foot using PHP

Tags: php

I have used this code which shows an error:ie if my meters is 175m but when i convert it does'nt show that thing

```
<?php
function metersToFeetInches($meters, $echo = true)
{
    $m = $meters;
    $valInFeet = $m*3.2808399;
    $valFeet = (int)$valInFeet;
    $valInches = round(($valInFeet-$valFeet)*12);
    $data = $valFeet."&prime;".$valInches."&Prime;";
    if($echo == true)
    {
            echo $data;
    } else {
            return $data;
    }
}
?>
<?php
$feetInches = metersToFeetInches(1.75,false);
echo $feetInches;
?>
```

Comment: Well... care to share the error message?

Comment: I ran your code and got `5&prime;9&Prime;` which sounds roughly correct (5 feet, 9 inches)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision) may help understand why your results are different from what you expect.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing as @pstrjds... which is why you should show us your error message. :)

Comment: @PeeHaa 5.9 is the output, but absolute is 5.74

Comment: @pstrjds 5.9 is wrong , 5.74 is correct, easy way to check the answer in google

Comment: @flep 5.74 is the right answer

Comment: @ede - I didn't get 5.9, I got 5' 9", the floating point value is 5.74..., you are taking 5.74... - 5, then multiplying by 12 which gives you `8.8976379`, you then round that. The correct rounded to nearest int value of 8.89... is 9. You are getting what you coded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those things you can easily find on [Google](http://www.google.nl/search?q=meter%20to%20foot%20php), but I guess you didn't look further than the first link.

Anyways, you should do it like this.

```
<?php

function metersToFeet($meters) {
    return floatval($meters) * 3.2808399;
}

?>
```

But why is this better than the code you posted? Well, functions are not supposed to do everything. You should write a function for a certain action, not one big function with everything you can every need. Because **if** you need to add something to that function or change the order of actions, it's a hell of a lot of work.

Furthermore, your function has an option `$echo`. But why would you need that? You can add such an option to every function, but PHP has a nice commando for that: `echo`. So instead, it's way better to write `echo metersToFeet(10)`. Or `$value = metersToFeet(10)` if you need to save the result in a variable.

Comment: Actually, this is the first result on Google. Your criticism is unwarranted sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function metersToFeetInches($meters, $echo = true)
{
    $m = $meters;
    $valInFeet = $m*3.2808399;
    $valFeet = (int)$valInFeet;
    $valInches = round(($valInFeet-$valFeet)*12);
    $data = $valFeet."&prime;".$valInches."&Prime;";
    if($echo == true)
    {
        echo $data;
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```