# Loss of significance php round

Tags: php, rounding

I have the following code

```
$suma += round(1*43067.8000,2);

$suma += round(-1*18875.1800,2);

$suma += round(-1*15293.9700,2);

$suma += round(-1*8898.6500,2);

print $suma;
```

The output is 3.6379788070917E-12

Why the answer is not 0 if the number is rounded before the addition?

Comment: Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision.  Round returns a float...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round still returns a float. Because it is a float there might always be very small errors. In this case, this causes your answer to differ from 0.