# SQL Float value not = 0

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with some SQL value & PHP.
I am doing 2 request, one to add a value into my sql and the other one to minus this result.

Here it is :

```
$totaux = $montant_actuel + ($nbre_dej * $prix_dejeuner) + ($nbre_din * $prix_diner) + ($nbre_soir_etape * $prix_etape);
```

When i'm doing this, it's equal to:

`sum = 0 + (15.8*1) + (15.8*1) + (57.8*0)`

So I have : 31.6

But when i'm trying to do :

```
$totaux = $montant_actuel - ($nbre_dej * $prix_dejeuner) - ($nbre_din * $prix_diner) - ($nbre_soir_etape * $prix_etape);
```

`sum = 31.6 - (15.8*1) - (15.8*1) - (57.8*0)`

And then, when i insert it into my DB i have this record : 0.0000000000000142109 instead of 0

I don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: You should read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision/3726761#3726761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like a simple rounding error inside the database. if you're using `float` or `double` change it to `decimal` to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: Decimal is displaying all 0 value after "," and rounding ? it's perfect for my use. Thanks you

Comment: decimal does not round, but you can specify the number of decimal places. if needed you can round manually in php before writing into the database.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a problem with precision of numbers... use some functions from: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)