# PHP subtracting numbers strangely - returning long float values

Tags: php

I'm calculating fees (monetary) for something and PHP is behaving strangely when the amount is supposed to be 0.00. It's giving the final result as a floating number, not 0 which it should be.

In My database I have the following table

```
id   |  transaction_total   |    charge_fees   |  deposit_fee   |   amount_to_customer   |   fees_minus_total_difference
```

So when I go to check to make sure that the fees + amount paid - total = 0.00

```
(96.54 + .25 + 3.20 - 99.99) = 1.4210854715202E-14
```

Why is the result a floating number and not actually zero? The numbers are originally more decimal places, but I used number_format to put it into 2 places. Ex, charge fees may actually be 3.19987

```
number_format(3.19971,2,'.','')  //equals 3.20
```

When I save this in my database it displays as 3.20. When I use it in the computation for the total/fee check, the result is not zero, albeit close.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Comment: Never use floating points for *monetary values*, unless you don't mind losing small amounts of money (or gaining some, maybe). Either calculate in cents or with an arbitrary precision library like bcmath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Math Precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computers store numbers in binary, so when you try to represent a decimal number you may lose precision. That is what is happening here.

Some languages have exact-precision types, but PHP, unfortunately, does not. It does provide you with both [BC Math](http://php.net/bcmath) and [GMP](http://php.net/gmp), though. Using those here seems overkill, though. Using BC, you could do this though:

```
bcsub(bcadd(bcadd('96.54','0.25',2),'3.20',2),'99.99',2) = 0
```

Notice that you have to specify the number of decimal points (2) here also.

Generally, using floats and double for finances is frowned upon, but with PHP it does seem like the simpler option.I suggest you just round your number using `round()` to the number of decimal places of your input.

```
round(96.54 + .25 + 3.20 - 99.99,2) = 0
```

Comment: You need to feed numbers as strings to the bc functions. Just writing `0.12345` in your source code has already made you lose precision. It should be `bcadd('1.234', '5.678')`.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend not using `number_format()` other than for displaying strings. Use `round()` instead.

Your issue is with floating points. PHP has more accurate math functions you can look at like bcadd, bcmul, bcdiv, etc...

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php