# Double? Integer? -- PHP

Tags: php

The following code generates two random decimal values, then subtracts them to get `$c`.

```
$a = mt_rand(5, 75);
$b = mt_rand(5, 75);
$adjuster = mt_rand(2, 20);

do {
    $decimal_selector = mt_rand(1, 6);
    if ($decimal_selector == 1) {
        $a = $a / 10;
        $b = $b / 10;
    }
    if ($decimal_selector == 2) {
        $a = $a / 10;
        $b = $b / 100;
    }
    if ($decimal_selector == 3) {
        $a = $a / 100;
        $b = $b / 10;
    }
    if ($decimal_selector == 4) {
        $a = $a / 100;
        $b = $b / 100;
    }
    if ($decimal_selector == 5) {
        $a = $a / 1000;
        $b = $b / 1000;
    }
    if ($decimal_selector == 6) {
        $a = $a / 1000;
        $b = $b / 100;
    }

    if($b < $a)
        $b = $b + ($a - $b) + $adjuster;

    $c = $b - $a;
} while((is_int($a) == true && is_int($b) == true) || is_int($c) == true);
```

The do-while loop is trying to ensure that `$a` and `$b` are both not integers, and also that `$c` is not an integer.  But I keep getting times where `$c` actually is an integer.

If I use `gettype` it keeps saying `$c` is a "double".  Why, when `$c` ends up being something like `7`?

EDIT:
I keep getting random infinite loops from this code below.  Any ideas why?

```
        do{
            $a = mt_rand(5, 75);
            $b = mt_rand(5, 75);
            $adjuster = mt_rand(2, 20);

            $decimal_selector = mt_rand(1, 6);
            if ($decimal_selector == 1){
                $a = $a / 10;
                $b = $b / 10;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 2){
                $a = $a / 10;
                $b = $b / 100;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 3){
                $a = $a / 100;
                $b = $b / 10;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 4){
                $a = $a / 100;
                $b = $b / 100;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 5){
                $a = $a / 1000;
                $b = $b / 1000;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 6){
                $a = $a / 1000;
                $b = $b / 100;
            }

            if($b < $a){
                $b = $b + ($a - $b) + $adjuster;
            }

            $c = $b - $a;

            if(intval($c) == $c) {
                $c_is_int = 1;
            } else {
                $c_is_int = 0;
            }

echo intval($c) . '<br>';
echo $c_is_int . '<br>';
echo $c . '<br><br>';
        } while($c_is_int == 1);
```

[image]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Note that you don’t have to write `== true`, it’s usually implicit. (In this case, it is.)

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this to see if `$c` is a whole number (possibly stored as a double):

```
if(intval($c) == $c) {
    echo "I'm a whole number";
}
```

See here: http://3v4l.org/ubPK4

Comment: @gtilflm Your infinite loop is happening because you set `$c_is_int` to 1, but you have no `} else { $c_is_int = 0; }` So once it's set to 1, it's always 1. It's working here: http://3v4l.org/XBuHD

Comment: Thanks.  I added that in, but... amazingly, this loop STILL isn't working.  I'm still ending up with whole numbers for `$c`.  I have no idea why.  I echoed `intval($c)` and `$c` and it seems to be producing weird results.

Comment: I updated the original post with some debugging code at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: If you run that code over and over, you end up getting whole numbers for `$c`.  I'm doing this on a WAMP Server... could that be an issue?

Comment: Do you NEVER expect whole numbers? I'm getting mix of whole and non-whole numbers. Isn't that right?

Comment: No, I don't want $c to ever be a whole number.  I'm ok with $a and $b individually being whole numbers, but not BOTH of them being whole numbers.

Comment: I just uploaded a screen snip of a weird result I got.

Comment: It's entirely possible for $a and $b to both be doubles, and yet $c is a whole number. I just got `a: 5.7 b: 24.7 c: 19` in one of my test runs. Sure looks legit to me, I still don't get why it's unexpected.

Comment: That's the role of the do-while loop.  It's to prevent $c from being a whole number.

Comment: `$c` can still be a whole number, it just breaks the next loop cycle. Or rather, the opposite (since you continue the loop when $c IS a whole number). See here: http://3v4l.org/N0FkP. The loop stops whenever the while condition is no longer true for $c.

Comment: I think you misunderstand do/while loops. Anything can happen inside a loop cycle (including _any_ value for $c), it will just then stop and not proceed with the _next_ cycle.

Comment: I just got this from your code: a: 4.4. b: 17.4. c: 13 (is NOT int!)

Comment: I think it's a floating point rounding error. I think $c is ending up at `12.9999999....` and then `intval()` rounds down, such that 13 and 12 are not the same. Rounding the number first before running through intval seems to work: http://3v4l.org/Abg80. But that's nasty. This might warrant a new question on PHP floating point handling.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision. One of those answers also suggests using `round()` first before doing floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I've reapplied your accepted answer, but the issue still remains.  Your edited answer still doesn't ensure that `$c` doesn't end up as a whole number.

Comment: To be clear: your loop isn't about _preventing_ `$c` from ending up as a whole number, but rather detecting when it it (or isn't) a whole number. Let me know if you have a use case where the `round()` approach fails to accurately tell you if `c$` is a whole number or not, since that is what it is meant to do yeah?

Comment: The loop should be preventing it.  I've reposted about this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365368/loop-not-working-correctly-floats-and-integer-issue-php

Answer (score 4):

A double subtracting a double results in a double, even if that number is a whole number

```
$c = (int) ($b - $a);
```

Comment: That's silly!  Anyway, I don't want to ensure that $c is an integer, I want to see if it ends up that way.  Won't your casting of `($b - $a)` as an integer make it be an integer?

Comment: if(($c % 2)==0) { /* this is a whole number */ } else { /* this is not a whole number */ }

Comment: @jszobody: I tried implementing your code and I keep getting infinte loops.  I've edited the question showing the code.  Any ideas?

Comment: @gtilflm I answered your infinite loop question in a comment under my posted answer