# Loop not working correctly (floats and integer issue?) -- PHP

Tags: php, loops

The code below generates two random decimal values, then subtracts them to get `$c`.

The do-while loop is trying to ensure that `$c` will not be a whole number.  But I keep getting times where `$c` actually is a whole number.

```
        do{
            unset($a);
            unset($b);
            unset($c);
            unset($adjuster);
            unset($c_is_int);

            $a = mt_rand(5, 75);
            $b = mt_rand(5, 75);
            $adjuster = mt_rand(2, 20);

            $decimal_selector = mt_rand(1, 6);
            if ($decimal_selector == 1){
                $a = $a / 10;
                $b = $b / 10;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 2){
                $a = $a / 10;
                $b = $b / 100;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 3){
                $a = $a / 100;
                $b = $b / 10;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 4){
                $a = $a / 100;
                $b = $b / 100;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 5){
                $a = $a / 1000;
                $b = $b / 1000;
            }
            if ($decimal_selector == 6){
                $a = $a / 1000;
                $b = $b / 100;
            }

            if($b < $a){
                $b = $b + ($a - $b) + $adjuster;
            }

            $c = $b - $a;

            if(intval($c) == $c) {
                $c_is_int = 1;
            } else {
                $c_is_int = 0;
            }

echo $a . '<br><br>';
echo $b . '<br><br>';
echo intval($c) . '<br>';
echo $c_is_int . '<br>';
echo $c . '<br><br>';
        } while($c_is_int == 1);
```

The attached image shows the results of one of these failing times.  Any ideas on where this is going wrong?

[image]

Comment: It's still not clear what the purpose of your code is. Not implausible that you're looking for e.g. [arbitrary precision math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) though instead of float/int juggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not check to see if the number has a decimal?

```
$c = 123.456;

if(strpos((string) $c, '.') !== FALSE) {
    // is decimal/float/double
}
```

You can also just check to see if it's an int

```
if(is_int($c))
```

Comment: I originally tried `is_int()`, but it kept failing for some reason (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364384/double-integer-php/20364537)

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep in mind that the integer 3 and float 3.0 will compare as equal when using the `==`.

Consider:

```
$c_is_int = $c == floor( $c );
...
while( $c_is_int )
```