# PHP: round up to the nearest 0.05 monetary values

Tags: php

I am trying to solve this problem:

> When I purchase items I receive a receipt which lists the name of all
>   the items and their price (including tax), finishing with the total
>   cost of the items, and the total amounts of sales taxes paid. The
>   rounding rules for sales tax are that for a tax rate of n%, a shelf
>   price of p contains (np/100 rounded up to the nearest 0.05) amount of
>   sales tax.

So, ... I have a price in php:

```
$value = 11.25;
```

and I don't understand why

```
var_export(ceil($value * 0.05 * 10));
```

returns 6 and dividing per 10, the result is

```
var_export(ceil($value * 0.05 * 10) / 10);
```

0.59999999999999998

---

**some nice experiments:**

```
php > echo bcmul(11.25, 0.05, 3);
0.562
php > echo bcmul(ceil(11.25), 0.05, 3);
0.60
```

Comment: Because floating point is not exact. Use `number_format` to round it to a particular number of decimal places.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read what bishop point out and also you could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision) in order to understand what is the problem.

Now talking about a solution, you could use [PHP BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension which should be used when you want to work with precision mathematical numbers

> For arbitrary precision mathematics PHP offers the Binary Calculator
>   which supports numbers of any size and precision, represented as
>   strings.

One solution (a ugly one) could be this

```
$value = 11.25;

var_export(bcdiv(ceil($value * 0.05 * 10), 10, 1)); // Output '0.6'
```

Here I am using the **[bcdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)** from the mentioned extension.