# json_encode retain float values as is it is

Tags: php, json, floating-point

I need to convert an array to json and want to retain the precision as well as type of the data.

```
   $a = array("num" => 10000.00);
   print_r(json_encode($a));
```

In the above example 10000.00 is being converted to 10000. How can I retain everything in the json.

Comment: there's no way retaining the decimal numbers without converting that to string

Answer (score 10):

The best you can do in php 5.6+, is to make sure it is encoded as a float. However, that does not keep the precision:

```
<?php
$a = array("num" => 10000.00);
print_r(json_encode($a, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION));
```

If  datatype *and* precision are important, you would need to send an additional parameter, for example:

```
$a = ["num" => [
        "value" => 10000.0, 
        "precision" => 2
    ]
];
print_r(json_encode($a, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION));
```

If you always want the precision of 2 digits (like monetary values), you should multiply the values by 100 and store these as integers to avoid rounding problems. Also see [PHP - Floating Number Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision).

Comment: Is it impossible to keep precision in that case?

Comment: @Harshit Unless you specify it (see my edit), the precision is unkown to php.

Comment: @jereon Actually I need it for some payment API which only accepts a floating point with a 2 decimal precision.

Comment: This is great as it'll keep float as float, however it will convert integers to float

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code segment to get your desired output -

```
$a = array("num" => 10000.00);
foreach ($a as $i => $number) 
 {
    $a[$i] = number_format($number, 2, '.', null);
 }

  echo $res = json_encode($a);
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for simply casting the value to a string ;-)