# How to json_encode float values with two zero decimals in PHP 8?

Tags: php

PHP seems to have a bug in the way it handles decimal precision in json_encode.

It's easy to see just by encoding a simple float:

```
echo json_encode(["testVal" => 54932.00]);

// Prints out:
{"testVal": 54932}
```

How I can get result like this:

```
{"testVal": 54932.00}
```

I need two decimals places (including `.00`) in json.

Comment: But this is the same value. What do you want to accomplish? If you want to get the exact formatting, then store the value as a string. If you want the numeric value - then `54932` and `54932.00` is the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json\_encode retain float values as is it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298424/json-encode-retain-float-values-as-is-it-is)

Comment: @AdrianKokot Actually if using strict comparison, then it's not the same. One is float and another is int, so when using `private float $testVal` it would throw error

Comment: @AdrianKokot I need send this on service, I need in json be 54932.00