# PHP sprintf('%d', floatval('16.40') * 100) outputs 1639?

Tags: php, printf

The sprinf behaviour below is very strange.

```
// The code below outputs 1639
$value = floatval('16.40') * 100;
echo sprintf('%d', $value);
```

But when I use `%f` it outputs `1640.000000`

I dumped the `$value`, it's definitely `float(1640)`.

Does anyone knows what happened when I use `%d`? Is this a PHP bug? I've tested in PHP7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Floating Number Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `$value` contains a floating point number. Floating point numbers are not exact, they are approximations.<sup>1</sup>

The value of `$value` is not `1640` but `1639.99999999999977262632`. When you use `%f` to print it, `printf()` rounds it to `6` decimal places and the rounded value is `1640.000000`.

When it is printed with `%d`, `printf()` uses only the integer part of `$value` and it is `1639`.

Use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) to get the correct integer value:

```
printf('%d', round($value, 0));
```

Or, even better, use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to get the value as string:

```
echo(number_format($value, 0, '', ''));
```

Both print `1640`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Think of `1/3`. It is approximatively `0.3333333333` but one cannot represent it exactly because it has an infinite number of `3` after the decimal dot. In mathematics, `3 * 1/3 = 1` but in real life (and in computers), `3 * 0.333333333` is never `1`, no matter how many `3` we put after the decimal dot. The computer programs usually round the value to some number of decimal places and it ends up being displayed as `1` but this doesn't happen always.

When it doesn't happen, another [question similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Floating+Number+Precision) pops up on StackOverflow.