# PHP saving precision float into MYSQL ends up with rounded resulting field

Tags: php, mysql, precision

I've read all over about arithmetic regarding floating point numbers, but I'm just trying to accurately store the darn things.

I have a mysql field with the type of `DECIMAL (40,20)`.

I am saving a value in php of `46457.67469999996`.  After updating the record with this value, the end result is `46457.67470000000000000000`.  Not sure why it's being rounded at all just being saved to the database.

The value is not being converted to a string or anything beforehand.  The field value that is passed into PDO is the value I expected to be saved and it is returned as a float...  Perhaps it's because I'm saving a PHP float to a mysql decimal type where the rounding is occurring?

What am I missing here?

**EDIT: Added example code that has the issue**

```
// Query placeholder variables.  Hard-coded for the example test
$query_vars = array(
    ":vendor_id"                    => 33154,
    ":year"                         => 2018,
    ":coop_committed_dollar"        => 46457.67469999996,
    ":coop_committed_dollar_update" => 46457.67469999996
);

$statement = "  INSERT INTO vendor_data_yearly
                (vendor_id, year, coop_committed_dollar) VALUES
                (:vendor_id, :year, :coop_committed_dollar)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    coop_committed_dollar = :coop_committed_dollar_update;";
$query = $connection->conn->prepare($statement);
$query->execute($query_vars);
```

When I run this, the resulting value of `coop_committed_dollar` is `46457.67470000000000000000`.  This code is legit all I am doing.

**Possible solution**

```
// Note that I am casting the string using the BC Math library.
// I dunno how to just initialize the number (lame documentation), so I'm adding 0 to it.
$number = "46457.674699999967";
$number = bcadd("46457.674699999967", 0, 20);

$query_vars = array(
    ":vendor_id"                    => 33154,
    ":year"                         => 2018,
    ":coop_committed_dollar"        => $number,
    ":coop_committed_dollar_update" => $number
);

$statement = "  INSERT INTO vendor_data_yearly
                (vendor_id, year, coop_committed_dollar) VALUES
                (:vendor_id, :year, :coop_committed_dollar)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    coop_committed_dollar = :coop_committed_dollar_update;";
$query = $conn->prepare($statement);
$query->execute($query_vars);
```

This results in the number as expected in the DB.

**ONLY SOLUTION I FOUND TO WORK CORRECTLY**

The data I am working with is passed in via ajax.  I had to take a few steps to get this to work correctly.

1. Use `ini_set('precision', 20);`
2. Manually set the data in question to be a string BEFORE sending it via ajax so PHP would not round it, extended with extra floating point madness, padd it, etc.

I found that PHP would just not let me reliably work with large numbers coming from  a variable set outside the script's scope (ajax).  Once PHP got it's hands on the number, it would do what it had to do in order to make it make sense as a float.

If anyone has a better solution for this particular scenario I'm all ears and eyes :)

Comment: Have you tried using a MySQL column type of double?

Comment: No I haven't.  From my understanding, decimal should be used if it's a monetary value.  Perhaps that's totally incorrec though: https://code.rohitink.com/2013/06/12/mysql-integer-float-decimal-data-types-differences/

Comment: If it's for a monetary value then decimal is certainly correct. I just tried manually adding your value to a decimal 40,20 column and it remained accurate and was not rounded. Perhaps the PHP code you are using is doing something you're not expecting.

Comment: are you typecasting to float before inserting into db

Comment: No.  I have added some code to my question that results in the rounded value as I described.  Hopefully it shows what I am doing properly for you guys.

Comment: The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of approximately 1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format). http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: maybe try to add `ini_set('precision', 20);`

Comment: @kallosz that allows me to utilize more decimals, however it ends up `46457.67469999995955700000`.  So now the issue is the other way.

Comment: Yeah since you're not actually doing any math, my suggestion for using BC Math doesn't help. However, the problem is what I described. I will edit the answer to focus on that part and remove the math suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that PHP's precision is not allowing you to store the exact number you think you are storing.
When you set `":coop_committed_dollar" => 46457.67469999996`
PHP is actually storing it as a different value, depending on the precision.

The solution is to store the value in PHP as a string instead of a float.

Since your question is: "what am I missing", I will try to provide an answer.
Basically it comes down to storing floats internally using binary representation. Since 46457.67469999996 cannot be exactly in binary (it ends up with an infinite number, similar to 33% (.3333...) in base-10), the closest rounding is used based on PHP's precision (set in php ini).

I was given a great explanation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision) that I asked a while back.

In your particular case, it also seems that the value that you are sending via AJAX is being stored as a float when parsed by PHP on the server-side. You want it to be stored as a string instead. If you're using json_decode, add this option: [JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#options).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to utilize this library with my question in mind?  That library requires all numbers to be initialized as strings.  How would I handle this if the number is coming via AJAX and starts out as a number.  PHP would lose the precision since I can't make it a string... right?

Comment: It will typecast to a string automatically in PHP and retain its value. So 46457.67469999996 will become "46457.67469999996"

Comment: I answered that (about string typecasting) hastily. I actually don't know. I am going to try to go play with it. I provided my answer based on an answer I got a while ago, and I dont remember how it all works tbh.

Comment: Because yeah you're right. If PHP cant store the number accurately how could it possibly cast it to a string correctly. I wonder if, when parsing the AJAX, you can parse it as a string instead of a number. After-all, ajax is a text-based protocol. It only becomes a number when PHP parses the AJAX.

Comment: If you're using JSON, add this option to json_decode in PHP: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING

Comment: I was thinking I may pass the numbers as strings.  Good to know!

Comment: Even if a JSON numeric value is unquoted, eg: {"SomeValue": 100}, the "100" part is transmitted as a string regardless. The parser on the other end will interpret the fact that it is not quoted as meaning it is a number. That's what the JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING is for. So being quoted or not quoted is really just a hint for the parser. Ajax is always transmitted as text (string). fwiw.

Comment: I posted a possible solution.  If you know how to actually initialize a number using the BC Math library, without doing operations on it, please let me know :)
This feels dirty tho.  Seems like I'm doing a work-around.  I might just be thinking about it too much.

Comment: I modified my answer. The key here is actually just the fact that you're using a string. That is the fix. I think the reason your work-around works is not because of bcmath. Its because you're using a string.

Comment: Makes sense!  I will need to use BC Math at some point I think, but this question probably will be answered thanks to you.  Once I ensure it works I'll make you as the answer.  Thank you for all your advice!