# PHP creating lease calculator

Tags: php

I have a given an example by my customer for lease calculator that divides amount to 1 payment per 3 months. This is the sample:

THE AMOUNT is: 320.49
The payments are set to 4 payments

```html
<table class="adm" width="100%"><thead><tr><th>Payment 1</th><th>Payment 2</th><th>Payment 3</th><th>Payment 4</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td><input class="short date mand" type="text" readonly="" name="vnoskadate[]" value="2019-10-17"></td>
<td><input class="short date mand" type="text" readonly="" name="vnoskadate[]" value="2020-01-16"></td>
<td><input class="short date mand" type="text" readonly="" name="vnoskadate[]" value="2020-04-16"></td>
<td><input class="short date mand" type="text" readonly="" name="vnoskadate[]" value="2020-07-16"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="short mand" type="text" name="vnoskasum[]" value="80.13"></td>
<td><input class="short mand" type="text" name="vnoskasum[]" value="80.13"></td>
<td><input class="short mand" type="text" name="vnoskasum[]" value="80.13"></td>
<td><input class="short mand" type="text" name="vnoskasum[]" value="80.10"></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

As per default I am dividing 320.49 / 4 to get 80.1225

By rounding 80.1225 I am getting 80.12 * 4 = 320.48‬ which is lower than 320.49

What principle shall I use to make all payments except the last one equal if the amount is not dividable to the number of payments?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: How is this programming related question? And why is it tagged PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the payments in PHP, you have two options. To make the last payment the biggest, use this code:

```
$amount = 320.49;
$payments = array_fill(0, 3, floor($amount * 100 / 4) / 100);
$payments[3] = round($amount - $payments[0] * 3, 2);
print_r($payments);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 80.12
    [1] => 80.12
    [2] => 80.12
    [3] => 80.13
)
```

To make the last payment the smallest, use this code:

```
$payments = array_fill(0, 3, ceil($amount * 100 / 4) / 100);
$payments[3] = round($amount - $payments[0] * 3, 2);
print_r($payments);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 80.13
    [1] => 80.13
    [2] => 80.13
    [3] => 80.1
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LhFH4)

Comment: Great solution Nick ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the remaining amount, and avoid the problem for [`PHP Floating point precision`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639952/2342558):

```
$tot = 320.49;
$qty = 4;
echo $singlePayment = number_format(($tot / $qty), 2, '.', '')+0;
echo '<br>';
echo $exceed = number_format(($tot / $qty) - number_format(($tot / $qty), 2, '.', ''), 10, '.', '')*$qty+0;
if($exceed > 0)
{
    // add this to the last payment
}
```

output:

```
80.12
0.01
```

Comment: #user2342558 what is '10' in $exceed row?

Comment: @Europeuser the number of decimal to consider in that operation.