# PHP Arithmetic Operations giving wrong result

Tags: php, arithmetic-expressions

I am just doing some simple arithmetic calculations in PHP and getting very strange results. Below, I have mentioned what I am doing and what result I am getting:

```
1. $a = 191.39 - 147;
2. echo $a; //Print 44.39
3. echo (191.39 - 147); //Print 44.39
4. echo -44.39 + 44.39; //Print 0
5. echo -44.39 + $a; //Print -1.4210854715202E-14
6. echo -44.39 + (191.39 - 147); // Print -1.4210854715202E-14
```

Can someone please tell me, why I am getting different value in Line 5 and 6 as compared to Line 4? Because I am doing same thing in Line 4,5 and 6 but results are different.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: [Also relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is to do with floating point precision as the 'weird' answer you are getting is just an incredibly small decimal.

See the [PHP manual on floating point numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Specifically, the big red warning box about precision.