# Laravel binding shows big number being applied to the query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that casts and returns the following:

```
$price = (double)number_format(2.97, 5, '.', '');
```

But when doing the query through Laravel Eloquent like:

```
$query = \App\Models\CustomersPrices::where('price', $price)->exists();
```

I wasn't finding the price in database. After some digging I did the following:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$query = \App\Models\CustomersPrices::where('price', $price)->exists();
$sql = DB::getQueryLog();

\Log::error($sql);
```

And the result is:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select exists(select * from `customers_prices` where `price` = ? ) as `exists`',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 2.970000000000000195399252334027551114559173583984375,
    ),
    'time' => 1.560000000000000053290705182007513940334320068359375,
  ),
)
```

Why is this happening? Doing `var_dump($price)` shows `float(2.97)`.

What am I missing?

Comment: PHP number precision is inherently buggy. Don't cast the number as a float, since it will already be a float after your formatting.

Comment: Some reading for reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision

Comment: @aynber it's a string after formatting.. The function `number_format` returns a string.

Comment: @aynber and my fields in database are double, so comparing doubles with strings..leads to problems. Maybe I'll have to cast the string to double while querying..

Comment: Yes, but it will be treated as a number, especially when passing it into your query

Comment: Float comparisons are not accurate. You can rather store dollars and cents in different columns.

Comment: @aynber it's not being treated as a number. It's actually being treated as '2.97' (from what I can see in the bindings..)

Comment: Right. If you run `select 2.97 = '2.97000';` in a database, it returns true. Quoted numbers still work when compared to non-quoted numbers.

Comment: @aynber take a look at this image: https://i.postimg.cc/sD2DnDrm/wtf.png

When comparing doubles with strings it's not returning anything.

Comment: If I do `WHERE CAST(unit_price AS CHAR(30)) = '2.97000'` it works. The field `unit_price` is a double (20,5).

Comment: How very odd. As shown in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal , it should work.

Comment: After some reading, the same sort of precision issue that happens with PHP also happens with float/double columns in MySQL. Decimal is a lot more exact.  This could be the reason.

Comment: @aynber https://i.postimg.cc/dwxcr9Lg/wtf2.png

Comment: Why `decimal` is the preferred data type for price columns. Also, I am willing to bet that casting isnt fool proof either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Comparing as string didn't work https://i.postimg.cc/sD2DnDrm/wtf.png

The solution was to firstly cast the field into a string and then compare both values as string.

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE CAST(price AS CHAR(30)) = '2.97000';
```

https://i.postimg.cc/dwxcr9Lg/wtf2.png

Comment: Just curious. If value is 25.50, does it work? For example, `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE CAST(price AS CHAR(30)) = '25.50';`

Comment: It doesn't because the column has 5 decimals, not 2. That's not a problem for me because my numbers always have 5 decimals.