# Conversion to int minuses 1 from result

Tags: php

I've got a cheeky little PHP issue with conversion to int where the result is one less than I believe it should be.

`(int) 4005 = 4005 (Correct)`

`(40.05 * 100) = 4005 (Correct)`

`(int) (40.05 * 100) = 4004 ??????`

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance for any help

Colin

Comment: That is a probably a rounding error. 50.05 cannot be represented as a float as the divisor is not a power of 2 (it's 5)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried to read the solution but I'm too stupid to understand it haha. Is there is a simple php solution that could make (int) (40.05 * 100) = 4005?

Comment: `40.05 * 100` is roughly `4004.9999999999995` ([fiddle](https://3v4l.org/c8j2t#v8.1rc3)). You can get an online IEEE 754 simulator if you're curious about the details. `(int)` truncates. If you want to round, you can use `round()`.

Comment: Can this issue be reopened as no solution has been made. The linked answer is in javascript and horrendously complex.

Comment: floating point number work the same in every language, and are a bit complex topic no matter how you phrase it

Comment: So what is the php solution?

Comment: See @ÁlvaroGonzález's comment - [demo](https://ideone.com/Nad6kO)

Comment: Apologies, many thanks guys that's perfect

Comment: Search "is floating point broken" and take your pick of hundered of pages of info

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision