# What is the best way to convert a decimal (float) to an integer?

Tags: php

I was trying to multiply floats containing decimals and was getting incorrect results.

For example, the following code does not calculate correctly....

```
$value = (int) (600.55 * 100);
var_dump($value); // outputs the number 60054 when it should be 60055
```

I was able to solve the issue by removing the decimal with str_replace...

```
$value = str_replace('.', '', 600.55);
var_dump($value); // now outputs the correct number 60055
```

But I was wondering if there is a more proper way to convert a decimal (float) to an integer so I can do basic math operations without having the numbers change

Comment: Use `round()` to round to the nearest integer.

Comment: @Barmar - I am trying to keep the entire number. For example, if the float is 600.55, I am trying to convert it to an integer of 60055.

Comment: I meant AFTER you multiply by 100. `round(600.55 * 100) == 60055`

Comment: FYI, removing the `.` won't work properly. Look at `str_replace('.', '', 600.50)`. It's `6005` rather than `60050`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Barmar! The round() solution seems to work!

Comment: It won't work with numbers like `600.123` -> `round(600.123 * 100)` gives `60012` instead of `600123`.

Comment: True marco-a, but I am only allowing two decimal places so it works great!

Comment: Why not include that in the question? That's a really silly way of asking 'how can I shift the decimal place by 2'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Let's understand why you get `60054`.**

```php
<?php
$value = 600.55 * 100;
printf('%.18f', $value);
```

The output is: `60054.999999999992724042`.

`$value` is a [floating-point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-floating-number-precision). Its value might not be represented in memory as you expect. It's an approximation. That's why, for instance, it's a very bad idea to use floating-point numbers for money. Probably it's fine for geographic coordinates.

**Why `$value = str_replace('.', '', 600.55);` seems to work properly?**

```php
<?php
echo 600.55;
```

The output is: `600.55`.

```php
<?php
printf('%.18f', 600.55);
```

The output is: `600.549999999999954525`.

```php
<?php
$value = 600.55;
printf('%s => %.18f', $value, str_replace('.', '', $value));
```

The output is: `600.55 => 60055.000000000000000000`.

```php
<?php
echo str_replace('.', '', 600.5599999999999);
```

The output is: `60056`.

When a floating-point is cast to a string, the string doesn't have all decimal digits. You'll get an “educated guess”. In your case, `600.55` was implicitly cast to `"600.55"` because the arguments of the function `str_replace` are expected to be strings.

**So what should you do?**

If you only want to multiply a number by 100, it seems rounding works fine:

```php
<?php
$value = (int)round(123.45 * 100);
var_dump($value);
```

The output is: `int(12345)`.

*Note:*  I read a comment saying `round(600.123 * 100);` gives `600122` instead of `600123`. That happens because 600.123 has more than two decimal digits, and the last one is lesser than 5.

But if you're performing lots of operations, it might fail:

```
$value = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; ++$i) {
    $value += .2;
}
var_dump((int)$value, .2 * 50);
```

The output is: `int(9) float(10)`.

There's a mathematical extension, [BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), to handle operations with decimal numbers that require precision. It uses strings to represent numbers:

```php
<?php
$value = bcmul('600.55', '100');
var_dump($value);
```

The output is: `string(5) "60055"`.

If performance is a priority, you may also implement a way to represent [fixed point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). Or splitting the integer and decimal sides:

```
<?php
$integer = 600;
$decimal = 55;
$value = $integer * 100 + $decimal;
```

The output is: `int(60055)`.